# WAAD authentication with SAML: LiveId is not supported

Tags: azure, saml-2.0, azure-active-directory, windows-live-id

I am developing a web application with Windows Azure Active Directory (WAAD) authentication support. In WAAD I added a user which already has a Microsoft Account.

[image]

I use SAML 2.0 protocol for authentication request.

In my app upon accessing a protected resource, I redirect the user to:

```
https://login.windows.net/<id>/saml2/SAMLRequest=...&RelayState=...
```

This is URL I copied from the WAAD management console:

[image]

The decoded SAML token looks like:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest ForceAuthn="false"
                ID="b6f579bb-c7fc-49b1-a8f1-bbe2ad99da5d"
                IsPassive="false"
                IssueInstant="2014-07-25T06:38:11.303Z"
                ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                Version="2.0"
                xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml2p:Issuer>....onMicrosoft.com</samlp:Issuer>
<saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"/>
<saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
</saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

This is working great, I am redirected to

1. https://login.microsoftonline.com/...
2. https://login.live.com/...

However, upon autheticating with a Microsoft Account user (which is also imported into WAAD), I get this error message:

```
ACS20031: Sign-in with LiveId is not supported for this application.
```

[image]

What am I missing?

1. On the WAAD web admin console I did not see such a setting. I tried both Single Tenant / Multitenant options
2. Is there a possibility to login with a simple WAAD user (not LiveId) with `foobar@<tenantid>.onmicrosoft.com` ?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge no.

Up to today, the only way to get users signed-in with Live ID to your Application are the following:

- Use [Azure Active Directory Access Control Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/) (or better known as ACS)
- Use the [LiveID Web Authentication SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx)
- Use the Azure Active Directory with a remark. The remark is:
  ** You can only use LiveID to sign-in with Azure Active directory, if you first provisioned that user in your directory tenant. Provisioning happens when you create a new user in your Azure Active Directory Tenant and in the process of adding, add it as a LiveID e-mail. Then you will have this user in your AAD but marked as "Sourced From" -> "Microsoft Account":

[image]

The type of federation you are trying to enforce currently only works for Microsoft Internal applications, and not for customers. The only federation service that currently works for Customers is the Access Control Service.

[Here you can read](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/22/azure-active-directory-is-the-future-of-acs.aspx) a bit about the future of ACS and the plans to merge these federation capabilities into next versions of AAD. But we still haven't got to that future.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use ACS, because I am forced to use SAML protocol request (and expect SAML protocol response). ACS only supports SAML 2.0 assertion with WS-Trust protocol, which is not enought. With WAAD I have already done provisioning a Microsoft Account user. I edited my question enriching with screenshots.

Comment: yes, you are correct, ACS does not support SAML-P protocol. But then you also cannot use federation with WAAD... login with regular waad user shall be fine working. what error do you get when trying to login with WAAD user (user@foo.onmicrosoft.com)?

Comment: I just tried again to authenticate with a WAAD user (user@foo.onmicrosoft.com), and now it is working fine. Only the provisioned Microsoft Account fails. Fortunately, I think that the WAAD user authentication is more important to us, and we can live without the provisioned Microsoft Account.